# Explosive growth of AtomicReference in a Groovy application

Tags: java, groovy, memory-leaks

I ran into a very strange behavior in my Groovy application, namely, it crashes with an OutOfMemoryError.
Heap Dump analysis showed that there was a memory leak somehow related to AtomicReference:

[image]
[image]

When trying to analyze the incoming reference of these AtomicReference, I got the following picture:
[image]

It seemed very strange to me, it looks like a memory leak somehow connected with the internal mechanisms of resolving methods in groovy.

I managed to reproduce this problem by setting Thread.sleep() at the start of my application. At the same time, I immediately observed an explosive growth of AtomicReference, which took about 65+% of the available memory.

Compiler: groovy eclipse compiler 3.6.0-03 and groovy eclipse batch 3.0.5-01

Groovy indy version 3.0.5

JDK 1.8 x86

Comment: I am not sure what is the question here. And Can you share your code so others can reproduce

Comment: Are you using memorized somewhere?

Comment: There is a call site cache in the runtime. You can limit its size or disable it with system properties.

Comment: @daggett, no, I do not use.

Comment: @emilles, how can this be if I compile my code with the -indy flag?

Comment: You can try setting this system property to 0 (this is from the indy side of things): `public class CacheableCallSite extends MutableCallSite { private static final int CACHE_SIZE = SystemUtil.getIntegerSafe("groovy.indy.callsite.cache.size", 16); private final MemoizeCache<String, MethodHandleWrapper> cache = new LRUCache<>(CACHE_SIZE);`

Comment: This snippet also shows where the memoized cache is coming from.  Each call site that gets a `CacheableCallSite` created will have up to 16 `MethodHandle` references cached for it.  In a large codebase, this can mean a lot of cached handles.

Comment: @emilles, For some reason, when this system property is set to 0, the size of the used memory does not change.